# (Ruby mysql2) How can I set it up so that failed DB queries just get logged and don't end the program?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Ruby program using the `mysql2` gem. This program iterates over large sets of data and makes lots of individual database queries using the mysql2 `.query` method. Occasionally, one of them will fail (usually because it's a duplicate of a previous row), ending the program.

I'd like to change this, so that when a query fails, the information is logged to a log file, the query is skipped, and the program continues to run. But I have no idea how I would go about doing something like this. Can anyone let me know where to start reading, or what I should be doing?

Comment: do exception handling, use `begin .. rescue .. end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Code that might throw an error in an `begin ... rescue ... end` block:

```
begin
  # code that might throw the database error
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  puts "An error occurred: #{e.message}"
end
```

Not that `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` will only invalid queries (like duplicate entries), but not other errors like when the db connection died. It is good practice to catch only the most specific errors you want to handle and not all possible errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. Exception handling isn't something I've studied yet (total beginner), now I know what to learn about next. Appreciated.